# What are extended modes?

Tags: optics, photons, terminology, photonics

What are extended modes?

I came across this concept while reading about photonics and photonic crystal. But I am not sure what is an extended mode.

Comment: May you share the link to one of your sources? It could be easier to understand the use of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could gather online (e.g. in [this presentation](https://www.iap.uni-jena.de/iapmedia/de/Lecture/Introduction+to+Nanooptics1461967200/INO_2015_2016_12-p-20002013.pdf)), an extended mode is a mode that can propagate in the bulk of the crystal.

Extended modes are contrasted with point defect modes (fully localized) and guided modes (localized only in one or two dimensions). The former can only appear inside photonic band gap, and the latter are in the allowed band, but can only have particular allowed directions in $\vec k$-space.